# Translating shell script into Windows command shell script (batch)

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

I have a shell script which makes directories `week_01` to `week_09` using a `for loop` and one another directory called `week_10`. I want to translate this shell script into Windows commands using two lines of code?

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( Y=1;Y<=9;Y++))
do
mkdir week_0$Y
done
mkdir week_10
```

Comment: Take a look at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html

Comment: @giordano thanks, still need some help..

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with DOS batch scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`for /L`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) makes a count-controlled loop in batch. `mkdir` remains [`mkdir`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490930.aspx).

```
@echo off
for /L %%y in (1,1,9) do mkdir week_0%%y
mkdir week_10
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (101,1,110) do (
    set "folder=%%i"
    set "folder=week_!folder:~1!"
    echo mkdir "!folder!"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another one!

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set folder=101
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
   mkdir week_!folder:~-2!
   set /A folder+=1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is really your task then this will work, too.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10) do Mkdir "week_%%a"
```